# Rails form => URL => JSON => Save params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, post

This is basically what I want to do, with the params given in a form, I want to do a GET/POST request to a site, this site expects an specific URL like http://site.com/user=XXX&size=XXX and it will give me back a JSON, I want to parse/save the data from this JSON into my rails app when the form is submitted.

I am totally lost with this manner, anything would be very appreciated.

Rails Form Data => Build the URL => Do a GET/Post request => Catch JSON => Parse => Save

Answer (score 1):

for rest api you can use activeresource in your application 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

if it's something very specific you can use Net::Http to make requests and then parse json to ruby objects by yourself.

Examples of using http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

for decoding json you can use
Json or ActiveSupport::JSON.decode  or this https://github.com/flori/json

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a request to another not your site to get the response. So you can install curb gem (the curl wrapper in ruby). Then use it to make the request on another site and parse json with standart RoR tools like Json to hash.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html  you get you can do the following:

at the top of your file add:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require 'json'
```

then in your controller or helper:

```
#set the uri
uri = URI.parse("http://my.site.com/uri")

#set the post params and get the respons
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"first_param" => "my param", "second_param" => "another param"})

#get the json info
data = JSON.parse(response.body)

#set result to an ActiveRecord (maybe there is a better way to do this, I guess it depends on the response you get
@something = Mymodel.new
@something.name = data["name"]
...
@something.save
```

Hope it helps!